# "NoMethodError" in my controller when trying to use "build_association" method on object? Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, associations

So I have three tables: locations, items, and ingredients, that have the following relationships between each other:

- A `Location` has many `Items`.
- An `Item` belongs to a `Location` and has many `Ingredients`.
- An `Ingredient` belongs to an `Item`.

When viewing an item (at show.html.haml), I want to be able to add in ingredients that it contains right there on the page, while using AJAX `remote: true` for the form. However, once I get to the `create` action of the `IngredientsController`, I am unable to do this:

```
@ingredient = item.build_ingredient(:name => ingredient_params[:name], etc..)
```

Point is, the controller keeps throwing `NoMethodError` for `build_ingredient`, `create_ingredient`, `create`, etc. Nothing works. But the relationship between `Location` and `Items` works perfectly fine.

The weird thing for me is, though, that this works:

```
@ingredient = Ingredient.new
@ingredient.build_item(hashes for an Item object here, etc..)
```

I am still quite a bit new to Rails and I practice every day. Normally I would eventually come across a solution online through Google, but this one has me particularly stumped and after reading the [Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) on associations, I have still not come across anything that directly addresses a kind of "3-Layered" association between models.

So here's what I have:

**Ingredients Controller**

```
class IngredientsController < ApplicationController
  def create

    # This works
    location = Location.find_by(:location_id => ingredient_params[:id])

    # This also works
    item = location.items.where(:item_id => ingredient_params[:menu_item_id])

    # This does not work
    @ingredient = item.build_ingredient(:name => ingredient_params[:name], :unit => ingredient_params[:unit], :value => ingredient_params[:value])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render nothing: true }
    end
  end

  private def ingredient_params
    params.require(:ingredient).permit(:id, :menu_item_id, :name, :unit, :value)
  end
end
```

---

**show.html.haml (Items)**

```
.panel.panel-default
  = form_for @ingredient, remote: true do |f|
    .panel-heading
      New Ingredient
    .panel-body
      = f.hidden_field :id, :value => params[:id]
      = f.hidden_field :menu_item_id, :value => params[:menu_item_id]
      = f.select :name, options_from_collection_for_select(Supplylist.all, "id", "item"), { :prompt => "Select..." }, :class => "form-control ingredient-select"
      %br
      = f.text_field :value, :class => "form-control"
      %br
      = f.select :unit, options_from_collection_for_select(UnitType.all, "id", "name"), { :prompt => "Select..." }, :class => "form-control ingredient-select"
    .panel-footer
      = f.submit "Add", :class => "btn btn-success"
```

---

**Location Model**

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :items

  @url

  def getResponse
      response = RestClient.get(
        @url,
        {:content_type => :json, :'Api-Key' => '000000000000000000000'})

      return response
  end

  def setURL(url)
      @url = url
  end

  def getJSON
      return getResponse()
  end

  def getData(url)
      self.setURL(url)
      return JSON.parse(getJSON())
  end
end
```

---

**Item Model**

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  has_many :ingredients
end
```

---

**Ingredients Model**

```
class Ingredient < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item
end
```

Also, just to note:

- The `items` table in my database DOES have a `location_id` foreign key column.
- The `ingredients` table in my database has an `item_id` foreign key column.

Both columns were created during model creation using `location:belongs_to` and `item:belongs_to`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `item` does not contain a single item.  Change your item query to:

```
item = location.items.where(:item_id => ingredient_params[:menu_item_id]).first
```

Then you can use:

```
item.ingredients.build(:name => ingredient_params[:name], etc..)
```

`build_<association_name>` is only valid for belongs_to or has_one associations.

Comment: Just tried this but it returned the following error: `NoMethodError in IngredientsController#create

undefined method `ingredients' for #<Item::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fb07c229118>`.

Comment: Are you sure the Item model defines a `has_many :ingredients` association?

Comment: I am most certainly positive it does. I can post the migration files if you want to see them.

Comment: Yeah, I have the Item Model listed above.

Comment: The problem is that `item` is not an instance of the `Item` model.  You've got a `#<Item::ActiveRecord_AssociationRelation:0x007fb07c229118>`, which tells me its a collection of items not a single item. I updated my answer with how to fix that as well.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you for pointing that out. That hadn't even crossed my mind. I changed `item = location.items.where(:item_id => ingredient_params[:menu_item_id])` to `item = location.items.find_by(:item_id => ingredient_params[:menu_item_id])`, which returned a single result instead. Then using the syntax you provided, it was built and saved successfully to database. Thank you! I will mark this answer as right.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could be of help.